# Div under div right aligned

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a layout only with divs which have different colours...So I have a problem in aligning 3 divs in the right side of the page, and it must look like this: div1 on top, div2 under div1, and div3 under div2.

```
div a1
div a5
div a6
```

Here's my html code:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>DIV</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="coloursCSS.css" type="text/css">
        <div class="a2">two</div>
        <div class="a1">one</div>
        <div class="a5">five</div>
        <div class="a6">six</div>
        <div class="VerticalSpace"></div>
        <div class="a3">three</div>
        <div class="HorizontalSpace"></div>
        <div class="a4">four</div>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

And CSS code:

```
.a1, .a2, .a3, .a4, .a5, .a6
{
    border: 4px solid;
}

.VerticalSpace, .HorizontalSpace
{
    border: 0px;
    float: left;
}

.a2
{
    height: 250px;
    float: left;
    background-color:red;
    width: 100%;
}

.a3
{
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.a4
{
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

.a1
{
    height: 20%;
    width: 23%;
    float: right;
    background-color:blue;
}

.a5
{
    height: 20%;
    width: 23%;
    float: right;
    background-color: yellow;
    position:relative;
}

.a6
{
height:20%;
width: 23%;
float: right;
background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean by div1, div2 and div3 since there are no divs with those classes or identifiers

Comment: it's pretty hard for me to show exactly what I want without pictures...div1,div2 and div3 are just for example.

Comment: I want `div1, div2, div3` like: `div a1, div a5, div a6` wow... </depressed>

Comment: In my case, i need div a1 to be on top, div a5 to be under div a1, and div a6 under a5

Comment: @user3183299 I mean there is no way for us to tell which is div1, div2 and div3. Label them in your code or something

Comment: div1 = div a1 ; div2 = div a5 ; div3 = div a6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x08j29m5/1

```
.a1, .a5, .a6 {clear:right;}
```

I added clear:right; to a1, a5 and a6, but I don't know exactly what you want to do, so there might be a more appropriate solution.

Comment: That work's! But now, there is a space between div a2 and div a3...I would be grateful if you try the code to see exactly what i need to do

Comment: I want the div a3 to be started from the end of a1, and to be ended at the beginning of a4...

Comment: I moved a3 just below a2 in the DOM. There is no more space at the top.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I do this, please?

Comment: Ahhh...I did this, it was logic :). Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then here is the html you need...

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>DIV</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="coloursCSS.css" type="text/css">
    <div class="a1">one</div>
    <div class="a5">five</div>
    <div class="a6">six</div>
</BODY>
```

All three of these divs are aligned right and are different colors.